# yum equivalant of the apt-get /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies file for running behind a proxy?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, centos6

I have been trying to get yum working behind a proxy setting
 `export https_proxy`, `http_proxy` and `ftp_proxy`.

This didn't work for **apt-get** or **yum**, but when I set these in **/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies** it worked a treat.

Is there any yum equivalent when working with centos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so looks like you set it in /etc/yum.conf

```
# The proxy server - proxy server:port number
proxy=http://mycache.mydomain.com:3128
# The account details for yum connections 
proxy_username=yum-user
proxy_password=qwerty
```